# How to shift a byte through multiple byte array

Tags: c, byte, bit-shift

I am working on LED Tower that contains 15 layers, where each of them contains 4 bytes (32 LEDs). I would like to be able to shift a byte from right to left. However there is an issue with multiple bytes, can't figure out how to continously transition the shifting.

Additional information:

```
void Invert_Display(void){
for (int y = 0; y < LAYERS; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < BYTES; x++){
        LED_Buffer[y][x] ^= (0b11111111);
    }
}
Update_Display();
```

Where UpdateDisplay function is as follows:

```
void Update_Display(void){

    while(!TRMT);           // Wait until transmission register is empty

    for (int y = 0; y < LAYERS; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < BYTES; x++){
        TXREG = LED_Buffer[y][x];
        while (!TRMT);
        }
    }

    LE = 1;                 // Data is loaded to the Output latch
    NOP();              
    LE = 0;                 // Data is latched into the Output latch
```

The expected outcome is attached below.[image]

Comment: how long shift 1 bit or 8 bits?

Comment: Well ideally i want to shift through all bytes (all LEDs) per each layer.

Comment: Can you pack your 4 bytes into one big `uint32_t`? If yes, then all you need to do is perform a 1 bit left shift: `my_uint32_variable <<= 1;` — or `my_uint32_variable *= 2;` for that matter.

Comment: I have to specify which LED_Buffer[y][x] I am using to shift the values in. Say I wanted to shift 0xAA value  starting from LED_Buffer[0][0] and finishing outside of LED_Buffer[0][3], so it sweeps through entire display. That is my end goal. 
* I added some code to give a better idea how it is done. I am using PIC16F1829 microcontroller to develop this.

Comment: I guess the main problem is that I am updating the display using bytes whereas shifting is usually done in terms of single bits, correct?

Comment: @RytisBe Nope. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will shift an array of bytes to the left. The number of bits to shift must be between 1 and 7. Shifting by more than 7 would require additional code.

```
void shiftArrayLeft(unsigned char array[], int length, int shift) // 1 <= shift <= 7
{
    unsigned char carry = 0;                        // no carry into the first byte
    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        unsigned char temp = array[i];              // save the value
        array[i] = (array[i] << shift) | carry;     // update the array element
        carry = temp >> (8 - shift);                // compute the new carry
    }
}
```

It works by storing the old value from the array. Then update the current array element by shifting it and logical-OR a carry from the previous byte. Then compute the new carry (the upper bits of the original value).

The function can be called with code like this

```
unsigned char array[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA };
int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
shiftArrayLeft(array, length, 1);
```

which will change the array to `{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x54 }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I am working with 2-D arrays. To be more specific LED_Buffer[y][x] is used in the code. Idealy "y" parameter is just to tell which layer I am working with. I tried modifying the code, but `error: (202) only lvalues can be assigned to or modified` emerged.

Comment: @RytisBe Given a 2D array declared as `unsigned char buffer[ROWS][COLS]`, you can shift each row with `for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) shiftArrayLeft(buffer[i], COLS, 1);`

Comment: Ok i got that. However, having a difficulty with modifying the code to allow entire 4 byte array to shift by 32 places.

Comment: @RytisBe I'm not sure what you mean. Shift by 32 all at once, or shift by 32 one bit at a time?

Comment: 1 bit at a time. I want to sweep it through entire 32 LEDS  that I am driving.

Comment: @RytisBe I see. That seems like the topic for a new question.

Comment: Thanks, i shall start a new topic with a descent explanation what I am trying to achieve.